# MultiCameraSensor question

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking for a way to synchronize multiple cameras in gazebo. I came across MultiCameraSensor and believe this may be what I am looking for. Does anyone know if MultiCameraSensor is capable of providing depth data as well (similar to DepthCameraSensor) as I would like to synchronize multiple depth cameras. Thanks.

W

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1458/multicamerasensor-question/) by [Dubya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13/dubya/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It currently does not provide depth data. But you can use stereo image processing provided by ROS.

Here is an issue to track this enhancement:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/562/create-a-multicamera-stereo-sensor

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dubya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13/dubya/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks for the response. Currently I haven't seen a plugin specifically for the MultiCameraSensor. Does one exist?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-17**:
You can create your own sensor plugin: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins